# Is there a way to code this shadow in css?

Tags: css, shadows

[image: shadow image]

I was wondering if there is any way to code the green shadow in that shape with css

Comment: Are we to assume you want the green bottom shadow, but no shadow to the right?

Comment: eugh. the colours on that graphic are playing havoc with my screen and my eyes. sorry.

Comment: This [blog post](http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/) has an interesting method to create a drop shadow. Demo: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can stack the horizontal and vertical offset values of the `box-shadow` property, alternating between two colors and specifying as many layers as you want, e.g.

```
 div {
     background: olive;

     box-shadow: 
     0 01px black,
     01px 0 green,
     01px 02px black,
     02px 01px green,
     02px 03px black,
     03px 02px green,
     03px 04px black,
     04px 03px green,
     04px 05px black,
     05px 04px green;

     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Thcvv/

Comment: This is a great solution, I just get this vertical green line in the shadow, and I don't know how to get rid of it. http://imgur.com/h0IbNMV

Comment: It looks like you might've mixed the order of the shadows up, can you post the exact code?

Comment: Yep, I've messed up the order, but I fixed it now. It works great. Thanks a lot, you're awesome  :D

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for the bottom shadow, without the side shadow, you could just draw a rhomboid shape below it:

```
div{
    height:50px;width:50px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: relative;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    background-color: #9F9;
    width: 50px; height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px; left: 5px;
    transform: skewx(45deg)
}
```